# VSCode - Lerna - Typescript - Monorepo Code Navigation

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, lerna, monorepo

We have a monorepo for all our Javascript related SDKs here at Sentry.
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript

If you clone this repo, set it up properly with 
`yarn install`
and then open any file like `packages/node/src/backend.ts` and try to jump to the implementation of another package like the function `limitObjectDepthToSize` that lives in the `utils` package.

First of all, if you did not build the project before (have all type definitions in place) this error pops up:

[image]

But even if you built everything before, `CMD+Click` on the function now always jumps to the built `object.d.ts` instead of what I really want is that it jumps to the implementation source file which can be found in 
`packages/utils/src/object.ts` instead of `/packages/utils/object.d.ts`.

[image]

My question now is, is our setup wrong, is there any option in VSCode or maybe `tsconfig.json` that fixes this code navigation?

Or is this a currently known limitation of VSCode in monorepo environments?

Any help is appreciated and I hope it's nothing really obvious I just missed, thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set `declarationMap` to `true` to generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. It will allow IDE to jump to correct line at implementation file.

> [TS Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html):
>
> We’ve also added support for declaration source maps. If you enable --declarationMap, you’ll be able to use editor features like “Go to Definition” and Rename to transparently navigate and edit code across project boundaries in supported editors.

Comment: The oscar goes to ^ this guy. Thanks very much!